# Using an argument to define an extraction operator in user defined function

Tags: r

I have created a function that uses the subset function. How do I assign an argument then have it used after the extraction operator?

Here is what I have now:

`function_test<-function(time1,size,Param){
  test1_in_equilibrium<-(subset(alldata,Time>=time1 & FinalPopSize==size)$Param)
}`

Given the following call:
`function_test(100,5000,Time)`
I would like R to expand it like so:
`test1_in_equilibrium<-(subset(alldata,Time>=time1 & FinalPopSize==size)$Param)`

Unfortunately when I attempt to run this function I receive the error object "Time" not found.

I assume I am missing an escape character or something similar but have been unable to find it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot add the `$` operator to a function call and you cannot use a variable with the `$` operator.

However, I understand that you want to get the column defined by the input variable `Param` from the subsetted data.frame. In this case you can easily write the function like this:

```
function_test <- function(time1,size,Param){
  reduced_data <- subset(alldata, Time>=time1 & FinalPopSize==size)
  test1_in_equilibrium <- reduced_data[, Param]
}
```

Comment: You are correct in saying that I am trying to get the column defined by `Param`
Adding this to my function makes it work, I just need to wrap the Param argument in single quotes

Thank you!